# Configuring rabbitMq on ec2, without losing data

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq, message-queue

I want to configure rabbitMq on ec2, but the issue is ec2 may stop and restarting it will give new instance not the old one, but I want to access the data which was previously in the queue.

Now I have installed rabbitmq in my local system which is working fine.

Comment: " ec2 may stop and restarting it will give new instance not the old one". This is only true for EC2 spot instances.  Data and private IPs on instances that are on-demand or reserved will persist for the life of the instance.

Comment: Hi @erik258 thanks for reply, I have a follow-up question, what if there is hardware failure in that case how will i handle the current messages in queue if its hosted on on demand server?